# Port existing control protocol to proto3?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protocol-buffers-3

I am trying to port an existing control protocol definition to Google Protocol Buffers (proto3) toward the goal of generating decoding (not encoding) tools and libraries that produce human-readable strings. This control protocol has numerous one and two byte fields; however, proto3 does not appear to support these types. How can I implement support for one and two byte fields? Can proto3 even help me accomplish this goal.

Thank you,
Ira

Answer (score 2):

Protobuf (any version) is not intended for this purpose; it is opinionated about the protocol - it does not allow you to map things to an existing non-protobuf protocol.